# Action in form using PHP

Tags: php

I have a problem. Because i'm new in PHP, i don't know whether this is right or wrong syntax. Form it's not working.

```
<form name="edit_client" method="post" action="index3.php?page=del&id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>&action=edit">
```

Comment: You are missing the = after id in your html

Comment: are you missing `=`? it should be `&id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>`

Answer (score 2):

No problem with that.

```
<form name="edit_client" method="post" action="index3.php?page=del&id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>&action=edit">
```

Just missed a `=` after `id`

Comment: What do you want it to work like?